# NSolve missing solutions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, special-functions, numerical-value

I'm having trouble solving the transcendental equation. For some values ​​of bi, NSolve obtains 6 roots, however when changing the value, it obtains 5. Graphing the function clearly shows that the root that is missing exists and is in the interval between 10 and 11.

This is the code running all the roots correctly

```
bi=0.515625;
g[β_]:=(β*BesselJ[1, β])-(bi*BesselJ[0,β]);
roots=(β/.NSolve[{g[β]==0,0<=β<=18},β])
Plot[g[β], {β, 0, 18}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{#, 0} & /@ roots]}]
```

And this is the same code with another bi value

```
bi=1.27188;
g[β_]:=(β*BesselJ[1, β])-(bi*BesselJ[0,β]);
roots=(β/.NSolve[{g[β]==0,0<=β<=18},β])
Plot[g[β], {β, 0, 18}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{#, 0} & /@ roots]}]
```

Comment: I think you should report this as a bug to support. As a workaround, you could use `Solve[...] //N` instead.

Comment: Solve shows the same bug!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Functions should use explicit arguments for all variables.

```
g[bi_, β_] := (β*BesselJ[1, β]) - (bi*BesselJ[0, β]);
```

A function that uses a numeric technique (e.g., [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)) should use [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) rather than [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and have its arguments restricted to numeric values.

**EDIT:** Used [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) on argument and used [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) rather than [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
roots[bi_?NumericQ] := Module[{bir = Rationalize[bi, 0]},
  β /. Solve[{g[bir, β] == 0, 0 <= β <= 18}, β] // 
   Quiet]

roots[0.515625] // N

(* {0.953584, 3.96325, 7.08857, 10.224, 13.3623, 16.5019} *)

Plot[g[#, β], {β, 0, 18},
    PlotRange -> {-5, 5},
    PlotLabel -> StringForm["bi = ``", #],
    Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
      Point[{#, 0} & /@ roots[#]]},
    ImageSize -> 300] & /@
  {0.515625, 1.27188} // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Do I miss something? This simply shows the bug again. And it does not only happen with the numeric `NDSolve` but also with `Solve`.

Comment: @DanielHuber - I wasn't paying attention. Corrected error.